# How to send a float number via serialport in python using xbee and how to receive it?

Tags: python, xbee

I am sending a series of float numbers via xbee, however on the receiving end I can't work with the numbers I'm getting.

Here is a part of the code

```
xs0, ys0, zs0 = 1, -0.5, 3
h1=0.01
k1=2


while j<=1000:
   for line in ser.read()
     xl=ser.read()
     xm=float(xl)
     xs=xs0+h1*(ys0+k1*(xm - xs0)
```

With this I get an error for "*unsupported operand type for -: 'str' and 'int'*"

Comment: The problem would appear to be in one of the four variables whose values you didn't show the source of.

Comment: @jasonharper Added! Thanks for notifying.